# LIMIT SPECIFIC LINES in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I'm trying to limit a table's display to one occurrence of a specific word in a row.

I have, let's say :

```
test, 21, Service, Youtube
test, 23, Service, Google
test, 24, Out, Youtube
test, 24, Out, Duck
```

And I want only one occurrence of the lines containing 24, and all the other lines. So I'd have :

```
test, 21, Service, Youtube
test, 23, Service, Google`
test, 24, Out, Youtube
```

This is just an example, the table is way bigger, but it's for the sake of clarity.
Thanks in advance,

Comment: why choose test, 24, Out, Youtube in preference to test, 24, Out, Duck or do you not have a preference?

Comment: Why did you want to keep `Youtube` instead of `Duck` because they are both 24?

Comment: Only because it's the first occurrence

Comment: Is there any column that represents the order otherwise makes no sense.

Comment: There is no way of establishing first in the published data is there anything in the actual data which would do so. also is that 1 csv column or 4 columns -please add table definition.

Comment: 4 csv lines, and I want all the lines before the one with 24 plus only the first that has 24

Comment: This does not take the latest, but merge the columns together which could be a possibility? else remove the group_concat.
`SELECT DISTINCT Table.Columns..., group_concat(DISTINCT columName) as comment FROM Table.Column;`

Comment: @Mads Sander Høgstrup This looks more like an answer than a comment..

Comment: @P.Salmon since OP ask for latest my awnser isn't 100% what he wants, so I just want to make sure that this might be useful before i post it as answer. Would be nice if OP could provide us the full SQL query to create this output, and also maybe post full SQL output before line id 24.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way of establishing first but a simple union may do

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t(col varchar(50));
insert into t values
('test, 21, Service, Youtube'),
('test, 23, Service, Google'),
('test, 24, Out, Youtube'),
('test, 24, Out, Duck');


select * from
(select t.* from t where instr(col,'24') > 0 limit 1) a
union  all
select t.* from t where instr(col,'24') = 0
;

+----------------------------+
| col                        |
+----------------------------+
| test, 24, Out, Youtube     |
| test, 21, Service, Youtube |
| test, 23, Service, Google  |
+----------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```